# jQuery: by click on div show text in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, textarea

I am pretty new to JavaScript and hope someone can help me to find a solution for the following:

I have a div with some text in it and an onclick event. 
How can I manage that when you click on the div it shows the text inside the div within a textarea and a button above it - similar to how you can edit your own comments on this page here ?

**How it looks on default:**

```
<div class="clickable" onclick="TheFunctionIamLookingFor()">Some awesome text.</div>
```

**How it should look on click:**

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn">BtnName</button>
<textarea id="myArea">Some awesome text.</textarea>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim

Comment: What does `showTextarea()` do. Can you show that code.

Comment: just a normal div within an HTML form

Comment: This might be out of the blue, but Maybe just Maybe, (Not quite sure how to do this), but I am thinking how about you try Google.com or event the JQuery API documentation on event and selector... just saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
function youAreLookingFor() {
    var awesomeText = $(this).html();
    var $form = $(this).parent();
    $(this).remove();
    var textArea = '<button type="button" id="myBtn">BtnName</button>
                    <textarea id="myArea">'+ awesomeText +'</textarea>'
    $form.append(textArea);
}
```

If you mean to give a different myBtn and myArea name for each clickable link, then you should give the clickable div an id too and start from there to create the id for the textarea and the button.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the missing information in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way out to make what you want i.e. to make **editable** div using an HTML property `contententeditable=true`. You may use the following syntax:

```
<div contenteditable=true>
    contents here
</div>
```

This facilitates **copy+paste image** in the div as well as **textual edits** i.e **applying fonts on the texts** using keyboard shortcut etc.

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USy54/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only javascript DOM elements , then

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.dip
{
display:none;
}
.dip1
{
display:;
}
</style>

<script>
function TheFunctionIamLookingFor()
{
document.getElementById("myArea").className="dip1";
document.getElementById("myBtn").className="dip1";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<div class="clickable" onclick="TheFunctionIamLookingFor()" >Some awesome text.
<button class="dip" id="b1" type="button" id="myBtn">BtnName</button>
<textarea class="dip" id="myArea">Some awesome text.</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```